# I get a cast exception when using Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground) and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, mongoose

I'm quite new to web dev and I'm actually doing a bootcamp course on udemy, but they won't respond to my problem and I can't find it on the internet.

I'm using mongoose and this is my code:

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String
});

var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);

app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    //fubd tge canogriybd wutg provied ID
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
             res.render("show", {campground: foundCampground});
        }
    });
});
```

It is throwing a cast exception:

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5bdf29526cb8bc0a83765ab6" at path "_id" for model "Campground"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/v2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)

I've search high and low and I cannot find an answer to my problem.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing an invalid Id. If you provide any invalid id mongoose can't cast it and find it. Please double check your id and send another request.

And try findOne() once also.